# MySQL In NodeJS is grabbing IDs from a database but it's changing the last 2 digits of it to 00

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript

I'm having troubles with MySQL for node, when I see the IDs on the DB, they look fine, but when I grab it with the MySQL (code below) the last 2 digits are replaced by 0, any ideas on what's happening & how to solve it? I also will attach a picture of the database data & settings [image: Settings] [image: Data]

```
dbPool.getConnection((err, con) => {
        if (err) throw err
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM node_1 WHERE gid`, (err, rows:guildData[]) => {
            if(err) throw err
            rows.forEach(row => {
                client.dataGuilds.set(`${row.gid}`, row)
                console.log(row.gid)
            })
        })
        con.release()
})
```

Comment: what's the data type in mysql? Could this happen as a result of loss of precision or sign when converting to a string?

Comment: @kevintechie It's a bigint, Length/Set of 20, No unsinged, No zerofill, Alow null, Default null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that DB bigint exceeds Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. You can use BitInt(x) to convert:

```
const x = BigInt(928711151708167415);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, instead of turning a bigint into a string, just store it as an string